# NMinimize seems to be on crack

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization

Say I have a crazy function, `f`, defined like so:

```
util[x_, y_, c_] := 0.5*Log[c-x] + 0.5*Log[c-y]
cost[x_, y_, l_] := c /. First[NSolve[util[x, y, c+l] == Log[10+l], c]]
prof[x_, y_]   := 0.01*Norm[{x,y}, 2]
liquid[x_, y_] := 0.01*Norm[{x,y}, 2]
f[x_, y_, a_, b_] := cost[a, b, liquid[x,y] + liquid[a-x, b-y]] - Max[a,b] 
      - cost[0,0,0] + prof[x,y] + liquid[x,y] + prof[a-x, b-y] + liquid[a-x, b-y]
```

Now I call `NMinimize` like this:

```
NMinimize[{f[50, 50, k, j], k >= 49, k <= 51, j >= 49, j <= 51}, {j, k}]
```

Which tells me this:

```
{-21.0465, {j -> 51., k -> 49.}}
```

But then if I actually check what `f[50,50,49,51]` is, it's this:

```
0.489033
```

Which is pretty different from the -21.0465 that NMinimize said.
Is this par for the course with NMinimize?
Floating point errors compounding or whatnot?
Any ideas for beating NMinimize (or some such function) into submission?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It certainly seems to be related to your function `f` not being restricted to numerical arguments, plus the symbolic preprocessing performed by `NMinimize`. Once you change the signature to

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ]:=...
```

The result is as expected, although it takes considerably longer to get it.

**EDIT**

We can dig deeper to reveal the true reason. First, note that your `f` (the original one, args unrestricted) is quite a function:

```
In[1423]:= f[50,50,49.,51.]
Out[1423]= 0.489033

In[1392]:= f[50,50,k,j]/.{j->51.`,k->49.`}
Out[1392]= -21.0465
```

The real culprit is `NSolve`, which gives *two ordered solutions*:

```
In[1398]:= NSolve[util[x,y,c+l]==Log[10+l],c]
Out[1398]= {{c->0.5 (-2. l+1. x+1. y-2. Sqrt[100.+20. l+1. l^2+0.25 x^2-0.5 x y+0.25 y^2])},
 {c->0.5 (-2. l+1. x+1. y+2. Sqrt[100.+20. l+1. l^2+0.25 x^2-0.5 x y+0.25 y^2])}}
```

The problem is, what is the ordering. It turns out to be different for symbolic and numeric arguments to `NSolve`, because in the latter case we don't have any symbols around. This can be seen as:

```
In[1399]:= 
Block[{cost},
   cost[x_,y_,l_]:=c/.Last[NSolve[util[x,y,c+l]==Log[10+l],c]];
   f[50,50,k,j]/.{j->51.,k->49.}]

Out[1399]= 0.489033
```

So you really have to settle on what is the right ordering for you, and which solution you really want to pick.

Comment: Wow, nice catch in spotting that issue with NSolve! Thanks Leonid!

Comment: @dreeves Daniel, glad I could help. For some while, I was quite puzzled - had no idea before that this may happen.

Comment: FYI, 51 and 49 are backwards in `In[1400]` (but you get the same result regardless!)

Comment: @JxB Thanks! I noticed, but had no time to correct. Will do soon.